# how do i fix broken Xcode 'git blame' / 'git log' panel?

Tags: xcode6, git-blame

for a while, i've been happy to have the capability in Xcode to use `git log` & `git blame` in the comparison panel.

at some point in the recent past, this panel has stopped showing anything.

in 'blame' mode, the panel is blank and the same color as my text editor.

in 'log' mode, the panel is white, as it normally is when it is showing me the git log for a while, but there's nothing in the panel.

i've tried turning off source control and turning it back on.

i've tried doing that and quitting Xcode and starting it back up, and various combinations of that.

i tried deleting & re-installing Xcode.

git blame in SourceTree still works in the repos associated with my Xcode projects (there are three repos, one per target), as does git blame.  but not inside Xcode.

i am looking for answers as to how i can re-establish my Xcode environment to show 'git blame' and 'git log' .

Comment: commenting on my own question … the problem went away after updating to OS X 10.10.2 … don't know exactly what was touched, but my Version Editor is back.  would still love an answer if someone knows what the OS update may have touched that would allow me to fix this if it happens again and there's not an OS X update waiting.

Comment: I am seeing the same problem now. Perhaps related, but maybe not, sourcetree is not recognizing uncommitted changes when available. I say perhaps related, because both symptoms seemed to start around the same time.